# Copying without visible text box

Tags: javascript

I've created a button that copies the value of a text box, I don't need the text to be visible but if the display is set to none the copy function breaks.

```js
function copyfunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("copydata");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="I will be copied" id="copydata">
<button class="button copy" onclick="copyfunction()">Copy</button>
```

Ideally the text box would be able to be hidden or the same could be applied to a button only without the need for the text element. The above works but I'm looking for a button only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a temporary input, see the example below:

```js
function setClipboard(value) {
    var tempInput = document.createElement("input");
    tempInput.style = "position: absolute; left: -1000px; top: -1000px";
    tempInput.value = value;
    document.body.appendChild(tempInput);
    tempInput.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(tempInput);
}
```

```html
<button class="button copy" onclick="setClipboard('I will be copied')">Set Clipboard</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the the new [Clipboard API writeText method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText) which is supported by most modern browsers (see [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_clipboard_writetext) for more details).

```js
//If you want to copyText from Input
function copyTextFromInput(elementID) {
  let element = document.getElementById(elementID); //select the element
  let elementText = element.value; //get the text content from the input element's value field
  copyText(elementText); //use the copyText function below
  alert('Copied:' + elementText); 
}

//If you only want to put some Text in the Clipboard just use this function
// and pass the string to copied as the argument.
function copyText(text) {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
}
```

```html
<input id="mytext" style="display:none;" type="text" value="Some Text to be copied"></input>
<button onclick="copyTextFromInput('mytext')">Copy</button>
```

If you want to use this directly on some text in a `div` or other element you can use the following:

```js
//If you want to copyText from Element
function copyTextFromElement(elementID) {
  let element = document.getElementById(elementID); //select the element
  let elementText = element.textContent; //get the text content from the element
  copyText(elementText); //use the copyText function below
  alert('Copied: ' + elementText);
}

//If you only want to put some Text in the Clipboard just use this function
// and pass the string to copied as the argument.
function copyText(text) {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
}
```

```html
<div id="mytext">This is some text that needs to be copied</div>
<button onclick="copyTextFromElement('mytext')">Copy</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set the `type="hidden"` and it'll do your work. As shown below:-

```js
function copyfunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("copydata");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" value="I will be copied" id="copydata">
<button class="button copy" onclick="copyfunction()">Copy</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the value for placeholder, then the initial value would be hidden and you could copy the new inserted value.

```js
function copyfunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("copydata");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="I will be copied" id="copydata">
<button class="button copy" onclick="copyfunction()">Copy</button>
```